# Saving worksheet as HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, file-format

I am trying to save the worksheet as HTML using job number cell B2 as file name, but I am getting an error; Expected end of statement on fileFormat:=xlHTML

This is what I have:

```
cell = Sheets("Data").ComboBox1.Value & Range("B2").Value
Fpath = "C:\Data\"
fname = Fpath & cell & ".html"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=fname FileFormat:=xlHtml
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on where the problem is?

Comment: It seams in the docu ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas ) that SaveCopyAs has only filename as parameter. Did you tried `SaveAs` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas )

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, now I got Compile error: Named argument not found, and the FileFormat was highlighted

Comment: I changed it to this: ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlHTML and I get Run-time error '-2147018887(80071779)'

Comment: What is the value of `cell`? Does it have any illegal characters in it?

Comment: The value of the cell is an integer, 5 digit,  I am wondering if the entire code is wrong??

Comment: so the combo box value combined with the range value amounts to just 5 numeric digits? is that value greater than 32767?

Comment: never ever use `integer`. there is no reason why `integer` should ever be used. always use `long`

Comment: Use `.SaveAs` and not `.SaveCopyAs`. **-.SaveCopyAs** is to create a copy of the file i.e `xls->xls`, `xlsx->xlsx` and not say  `xls->xlsx` or  `xls->xlsm` or  `xlsx->.Html`

Comment: thank you all for your input, sorry for not being clear.  Value in the combo box is an active combo box, and it only holds work order numbers and therefore not a variable.  What I hoped to achieve is to save another copy to a different folder under HTML.  I have tried all of the suggestions but still no go.  I have checked thru my code, and everything seems fine, can anyone see the issue?  Thank you

Comment: I keep getting compile error and FileFormat:=xlHTML was being highlighted, and when I changed to ActiveWorkbook.SaveFileAs, I get Runtime error 438.